# Validate a property with multiple conditions and multiple messages in Laravel/Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-livewire, laravel-validation

i want to validate a property with two conditionals and custom theses messages. i don´t know how to separate the rules and the messages in this case

There are two condition to $licences_days. The first one, if licences_available is greater than 2, you only can take more than 3 licences_days. Else if licences_available is less or equal than 3, you only can take from 1 to 3 licences_days. But, there is an error. How i can resolve it?

```
public $licences_days;
public $licences_available;

 protected $rules = [
    'licences_days' => 'required_if:licences_available,gt,2|integer|min:3|licences_available', // the first condition
    'licences_days' => 'required_if:licences_available,lte,3|integer|min:1|max:3', // second condition
];
 
protected $messages = [
    'licences_days.required_if:licences_available,gt,3|integer|min:3|licences_available' => 'the licences available are greater than 3, you can´t take less than 3 licences', // custom message for the first condition
    'licences_days.required_if:licences_available,lte,3|integer|min:1|max:3' => 'the licences available are less or equal than 3, you can´t take more than 3 licences', // custom message for the second condition
];
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can't have the same array key multiple times; PHP will only keep the 2nd one, so `'licences_days'` being repeated twice is not valid. Also,  `'licences_days.required_if:licences_available,gt,3|integer|min:3|licences_available'` is not a valid message key... That would be `'licenses_days.required_if' => 'Your custom message'`. You'll likely need to create a Custom Rule here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules, then `'licences_days' => [new CustomRule()]`, and `'licences_days.custom_rule' => 'Your custom message'`

Comment: idk how to bring licences_available as a auxilary prop to the rule